# Structural Estimation, Simulations, and Initial Values

Tags: econometrics, firm, simulations, structural-estimation, gmm

I want to estimate model parameters and fear about the impact of initial values of simulations.

---

**Short model overview**

Consider a firm producing a homogeneous output good whose output price, $P_t$, is $$dP_t=mP_tdt+s P_t dW_t.$$

Denoting the production output by $Q_t$, the firm's profits, $\Pi_t$, are $$\Pi_t=P_tQ_t-C(Q_t),$$ where $C(Q_t)$ is a cost function.

Suppose $C(Q_t)=c_0+c_1Q_t+c_2Q_t^2$ with $c_0,c_1,c_2\geq0$.

The model includes further state variables and choice variables (investment rates, equity issuance, etc.).

---

**Estimation by moment matching**

To estimate the model, I simulate many firms (arising from different shocks $dW_t$ and find their optimal production/financing/... policies) and seek parameter values which make the simulated firms behave like firms in the real data (e.g., match average capacity utilization and investment rates, etc.). The estimator is thus the [method of simulated moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_simulated_moments) (SMM).

---

**My Question**

The simulated panel somewhat depends on the initial values, $P_0$. If $P_0$ is high, then so is $P_t$ and $Q_t$. In particular fixed costs like $c_0$ would fail to correct for these changes: If $P_0$ is very large, then $P_tQ_t$ is large and $c_0$ can be large. But if $P_0$ is small, then so is $P_tQ_t$ and $c_0$ can't be large (otherwise the firm never produces anything).

However, estimation results should be independent of initial values? As output price is a geometric Brownian motion, there is no stable, long-run, stationary distribution from which I could draw initial values.

**Q:** How do I avoid that the simulated panel (and thus my estimated parameters) depends on the initial values of my simulations?